# Facebook Graph API question

Tags: facebook, graph, oauth

When looking at the Graph API documentation, I noticed that in this page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api
there are links to say, my own friend list (http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends) that have an access token that seems to be generated out of nothing and has very little privileges.
What is this token? Is there anyway to generate it myself without going to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has implemented [oauth v2 draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2)

You need to have active user session or permanent tokens (which could be taken from active user session, which permits permanent access grant)

More detailed at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this, but I dont understand where that specific token comes from.
It seems to be independent of an application key, so how can I as a user generate it, without having an application key?

Comment: @Alon Liv: "It seems to be independent of an application key, so how can I as a user generate it, without having an application key? " -- sure, it is dependant. Any token-secret pair belongs to specific application. You cannot get it if you are not application owner.